# Setting multiple Python variables at once does not always work as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've found that setting integer variables all at once works as expected:

```
foo = bar = cue = 0
foo += 1
bar += 2
print(foo, bar, cue)

1 2 0
```

However, when doing the same thing with a list type, it updates all of the vars at the same time. The resulting vars will always equal one another.

```
foo = bar = cue = []
foo += [1]
bar += [2]
print(foo, bar, cue)


[1, 2] [1, 2] [1, 2]
```

Why does the behavior differ depending on the variable type? Thanks much.

Comment: In the first example, you are assigning entirely new values to `foo` and `bar`; the previous value they held is completely irrelevant.  In the second example, you are mutating the existing value of the variables - and since they all refer to the same object, they all see the changes.

Comment: There's no difference in the initial binding/assignment. In both cases, all variables will be pointing to the same underlying object, whether its an integer or a list. The difference is that integers are immutable, whereas lists are mutable. The `+=` operation performs the `__iadd__` method, which on lists is an in-place operation (it mutates the object), whereas for integers it will rebind the variable to a different integer object (equivalent to `foo = foo + 1`)

Comment: The short explanation is that `+=` works differently for integers and lists.

Comment: They are all the same list, and the addition extends the list, it does not perform addition on the elements in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The augmented assignment operator `+=` hooks into the datamodel magic method `__iadd__` ("in-place addition"). If this method doesn't exist, it falls back to using the regular `__add__` method. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=iadd#object.__iadd__):

> These methods should attempt to do the operation in-place (modifying self) and return the result (which could be, but does not have to be, self). If a specific method is not defined, the augmented assignment falls back to the normal methods.

It happens that `int` doesn't define `int.__iadd__`, because it does not make sense to do anything "in-place" on an [immutable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-immutable) type.

```
>>> int.__iadd__
AttributeError: type object 'int' has no attribute '__iadd__'
```

However, `list` does implement it, and "extends" the existing list with elements taken from iterating the right hand side:

```
>>> list.__iadd__
<slot wrapper '__iadd__' of 'list' objects>
```

So when `foo == 0`, the augmented assignment `foo += 1` does something like this:

```
foo = foo.__add__(1)  # returns a different integer instance
```

Whereas when `foo == []` the augmented assigmnent `foo += [1]` does something more like this:

```
foo = foo.__iadd__([1])  # modifies foo in-place and returns foo again
```

It follows that `foo`, `bar`, and `cue` are names bound to different integer objects in the first case, but bound to the same list instance in the second case.

Comment: Perfectly explained and makes total sense. Thanks so much!